# Good practice for a global variable/function

Tags: python, python-import, gettext

I run into the problem that only parts of my project are translated/localized properly.

The problem is that the `gettext` function `_` is defined differently in two modules. `print_text1()` gets translated and `print_text2()` does not.

The solution seems to have some sort of global variable or flag for the language. What would a solution look like that is considered as good practice?

**Module A.py**

```py
import gettext
from B import *

language='de'

if language is 'de':
    de = gettext.translation('base', localedir='locales', languages=['de'])
    de.install()
    _ = de.gettext
else:
    _ = gettext.gettext

def print_text1():
    print(_("Power consumption"))

print_text1()
print_text2()
```

**Module B.py**

```
import gettext

_ = gettext.gettext

def print_text2():
    print(_("Warm Water"))
```

Comment: `language is 'de'` is troublesome. Compare equality not identity, i.e. `language == 'de'`

Comment: Easiest is to use [`gettext.install`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install) in your main module. This adds `_` to the builtins namespace, meaning you don't need to import anything in other modules at all. However, note that this means that modules cannot be used individually anymore without the main module, so it's not great for modularity.

Comment: Alternatively you can create the `_` object in the same way you are doing now, but in a separate module, then import it everywhere where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problems started to appear, when I tried to fix all the Linter errors that Pylance showed in VS Code. In order to fix the Linter issues, I did the same as you did in your module B.py, I added everywhere the definition for "_":

```
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext
```

That solved the Linter problem, but introduced the real problem!

As @Thomas mentions, install() already provides "_" to the builtin namespace. Surprisingly the direct assignement seems to brake something...

If you print the variable "_" in module A.py just before print_text2() is called, you will most likely see something like:

```
<bound method GNUTranslations.gettext of <gettext.GNUTranslations object at 0x0000018F134D0148>>
```

Whereas, if you print "_" inside the print_text2(), you can expect something similar to:

```
<function gettext at 0x0000018F72758B88>
```

which means, that the assignement of "_ = gettext.gettext" is actually something else than what install() does.

I ended up deleting all occurrences of "_ = gettext.gettext". With that, all translations work like a charm.

But, how to solve the Linter problem?

Here, I found these instructions: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1660

If applied to my problem, point number 4 proposes to add the following lines to each script:

```
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    _: Any = None
```

I now stored the above lines in a file called pylance_ignores.py and I import this file in any file, which uses "_". Like this the Linter is happy, all translations work, so I'm happy as well.